# Parent/child process close file descriptor

Tags: linux, file, fork, parent-child, system-calls

If you do a `fork()` on a parent and create a child process, and then the child closes the `fd` (file descriptor) inherited from the `fork` (parent).

Would the file stay open in the parent, since they're independent? What about standard i/o or stderr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of whether a file descriptor represents a file or a device, and regardless of whether it was ever passed as a standard i/o descriptor to any process: if you close it in one process, the other process still has a valid descriptor.

(This is pretty natural.  Imagine for a moment that the descriptor would be interdependent with the descriptor in the other process.  Then, if a child process unexpectedly crashed, the parent process would have difficulty to even log this fact, once the crash was detected.  It could not log the fact through any previously open descriptor, because all forms of process exit involve closing of all open descriptors.  Failure modes would therefore tend to spread across processes.  In addition, even regular, error free I/O patterns through such hypothetical shared descriptors would abound in race conditions.)

Comment: if they are independent, how the child reads what was written by the parent?

Comment: @Filipe - They are independently opened and independently accessed descriptors to the same file or device.  Or to one or the other end of the same pipe, if that's what you have in mind; but pipes are special in that they don't exist independently of their descriptors.

Comment: Is it right to say that it works like a document in a cloud? I mean, everyone who has access can edit it (write), but if someone closes it, it is still open for the others.

Comment: @Filipe - Yes that's similar.  But not a perfect analogy.  If you have access, that doesn't mean that you have the file actively open right now.  It just means that you will be able to open it when you try to.  The forked processes are like users who have the file opened right now.

Comment: @JirkaHanika - it means that both the parent and child processes should close the file descriptor (when they are done)?

Comment: @GuyAvraham - Yes, each process can close any resource whenever it knows it will never need that resource again.  However, it is rather customary to leave descriptors such as stdin, stdout, stderr open until the child process terminates which closes all of them implicitly.